# How do I make app engine flexible to connect to container engine via internal IP

Tags: google-app-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to configure App Engine Flexible to talk to Container Engine.

It appears that App Engine Flexible is just a container engine that is deployed with some automatic features. And by default, it uses network "default"

For container engine, it is also deployed with in network "default".

And I followed the instruction from https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/internal-load-balancing
 to configure an internal load balancing ip for the kubernete cluster.

[image]

I then checked my appengine instance IP through SSH. The IPs are obviously in the same subnet but I am still unable to access it. However, using external IP is totally fine.

[image]

According to: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/

> A VPC network is a virtual version of the traditional physical
>   networks that exist within and between physical data centers. A VPC
>   network provides connectivity for your Compute Engine virtual machine
>   (VM) instances, Container Engine containers, App Engine Flex services,
>   and other network-related resources.

So I assume this should work? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to connect GAE Flex app => GKE by using the internal LB IP? Or are you doing in the opposite direction? Can you provide more details?

Comment: GAE flex = > GKE, nvm I already figure out. Document was wrong , and it was so frustrating to figure it out after two days

Comment: Can you please share what was wrong about the documentation? I'd like to follow up internally to get that fixed.

Comment: In the config.yaml in IBL doc, Labels: app: echo. Should be run:[service-name]. It's such a simple mistake but it will catch a lot of people who is not familiar with kubernete off guard. Because the internal load balancer still gets created, but no endpoint will be connected to. Also, you guys might want to write a article specifically for how the VPC can help connecting between different products or if it can't yet. Like GAE standard at the moment.